# access all xml value in python, where there's several that have the same name

Tags: python, xml

In my application, I receive informations from amazon in xml. So, I read and access the values by simplexml.

My problem is when I want to access several neighbor strings that have the same name.
an example :

```
<ItemAttributes>
<Author>Brian Herbert</Author>
<Author>Kevin J Anderson</Author>
<Author>Frank Herbert</Author>
<Binding>Paperback</Binding>
<EAN>9782221088913</EAN>
```

I want to have the three authors ! Frank and Brian Herbert, and Anderson too.

Here are my results as I launch each command :

```
        >>> for cle in xml['ItemSearchResponse']['Items']['Item'][1]['ItemAttributes'].values():
...     print cle
... 
749782221088913
Robert Laffont
2221088913
9782221088913
Frank Herbert
{u'EANListElement': u'9782221088913'}

        >>> for item in enumerate(xml['ItemSearchResponse']['Items']['Item'][1]['ItemAttributes']['Author']):
...     print item
... 
F
r
a
n
k

H
e
r
b
e
r
t
```

So I access only the last item of the list, whereas there's several. How can I do ?
Under PHP, I did "foreach author in xml['...']['Author']; print author" and it was good. Here, this solution is the second I wrote just up, and it doesn't gave the expected result !
Any idea how I can access the authors' names one by one ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it seems the lxml.objectify solution is the best.
It allow to fellow the path you know inside the xml.
Plus, I didn't say you (sorry), but the xml is much more complex and deep than what I explain earlier.
It doesn't begin with ItemAttributes -> authors.

It's much more :

Items (there's other nodes inside the xml) -> Item (one item per book I find !) -> ItemAttributes -> …

Using lxml.objectify, I could find anything I need. The only hard point was to solve the common problem that when a tag or value doesn't exist, everything crashed.
I simply use try :

```
try:
    dico["title"] = unicode(xml.Items.Item.ItemAttributes.Title)
except AttributeError:
    dico["title"] = ''
```

That's it !
The above code show you how I use the xml path.

Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 1):

Is this the [simplexml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplexml) library you are using?  It hasn't been updated since 2005 (http://freecode.com/projects/simplexml).

Since I don't see any documentation for the library on the PyPI page nor on the project page I can't help very much with it.

The output of your code indicates that you iterated over a string.

I can, however, recommend using [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree) in the standard library.  It is easy to work with, currently supported, and I know it provides child elements as a list regardless of the uniqueness (or not) of the element tag.

Comment: I use this simplexml python library : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-simplexml/0.1.4
It's pretty current.

Comment: Okay, that's useful information. It's not out of date, but it converts a node subtree to a dict using the element tag as the key.  Since the element's tag name is the key in a dict, only the last element's text value will be returned.  (the code is short enough to just read it) My conclusion is that you'll need to use a different XML handling library to handle the data you presented.

Comment: Thanks dsh. I agree with you, and will try the one zach proposed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example using ElementTree:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

>>> xml="""<ItemAttributes>
<Author>Brian Herbert</Author>
<Author>Kevin J Anderson</Author>
<Author>Frank Herbert</Author>
<Binding>Paperback</Binding>
<EAN>9782221088913</EAN>
</ItemAttributes>"""

>>> root = ET.fromstring(xml)

>>> for author in root.iter('Author'):
    print author.text


Brian Herbert
Kevin J Anderson
Frank Herbert
```

I hope this helps.

Thank you.